# how can I read this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can anybody help me to read this callback array in jQuery?

```
{ 
  "message-count":1, 
  "error-text": "Invalid Phone format. Please ensure phone number to be in international format. e.g 447876567655." 
}
```

Comment: That's not an array, it is an object by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`JSON.parse()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [**`$.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

```
var a=JSON.parse('{ "message-count":1, "error-text":"Invalid Phone format. Please ensusure phone number to be in international format. e.g 447876567655 ." } ');

$.each(a,function(i,v){
   console.log(i+':'+v);
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/ne24p/)

Answer (score 3):

Yours is a JSON response, simply use [**Bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

```
var data = { "message-count":1, "error-text":"Invalid Phone format. Please ensusure phone number to be in international format. e.g 447876567655 ." };
alert(data['message-count']);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/tgZ6d/)